# Populate Cells in Excel, from Access using Input Box User input

Tags: excel

I'd like to have a user input in Excel that when entered, queried an Access database and pulled back certain fields to auto populate Excel. For example "Product ID:320" when entered would populate the Product Type Field, Price, Stock Quantity.
Any advice most welcome.

Comment: Menu "Data", "Get Data" button, "From Database", "From Microsoft Access Database", ..., I think it's a good idea to create the SQL query in the Access database first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.